# Confused by generics - pointer type parameter?

Tags: go, generics

I'm confused by generics.  I've read a bunch of answers to similar questions and I'm still stumped.

I get that the answer here involves telling the compiler that T and *T are related.  That while the implicit type conversion from one to the other happens normally in straight code, that doesn't happen in generics without more code.  Could someone please walk me through this?

```
package main

type Mungeable interface {
    Munge() // a Mungeable is a thing that can be Munge'd
}

type Box[T Mungeable] struct {
    Contents *T // A box is a type based on a Mungeable
}

type Foo struct{} // Foo is a struct...

func (f *Foo) Munge() {} // ...that can be munged.

func (b *Box[Foo]) Print() {
    _ = b.Contents.Munge()
}
```

produces:

```
./prog.go:16:17: b.Contents.Munge undefined (type *Foo is pointer to type parameter, not type parameter)

Go build failed.
```

what do I need to change to get this to compile?

playground here: https://go.dev/play/p/gNqxWhlmWmz

Answer (score 0):

`Mungable` is an interface, a pointer to an interface has no method-set (unlike a pointer to concrete type, which has a method-set containing the methods of its base type in addition to whatever methods were declared for the pointer type), so you need to dereference the pointer before calling the interface's method.

Another issue is that `Munge` does not have a return value, therefore the assignment statement `_ = ...Munge()` will cause a compile time error.

The following works:

```
package main

type Mungeable interface {
    Munge() // a Mungeable is a thing that can be Munge'd
}

type Box[T Mungeable] struct {
    Contents *T // A box is a type based on a Mungeable
}

type Foo struct{} // Foo is a struct...

func (f *Foo) Munge() {} // ...that can be munged.

func (b *Box[Foo]) Print() {
    (*b.Contents).Munge()
}

func main() {}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/HWW6k47Cdvh

Comment: Your answer is wrong, `Foo` does not implement `Mungeable`, `*Foo` does. The reason your example compiles fine is because `func (b *Box[Foo]) Print()` does not declare a method of `Box[Foo]`, it declares a method of `Box` with the type parameter being called `Foo` instead of `T` inside the method, changing `b` to be a function parameter reveals "./prog.go:15:19: Foo does not implement Mungeable (Munge method has pointer receiver)"

Comment: @QuânAnhMai I've answered OP's *"what do I need to change to get this to compile?"*  question, so the answer isn't wrong, perhaps incomplete, maybe even unhelpful, but not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of methods and interfaces is wrong. The method set of `Foo` includes those that defined with the receiver of type `Foo`, while the method set of `*Foo` includes methods defined with the receiver of both types `Foo` and `*Foo`. Given these declarations

```
type Mungeable interface {
    Munge()
}

type Foo struct {}

func (f *Foo) Munge() {}
```

Then `Foo` does not implement `Mungeable`, it is `*Foo` that does so. This is reflected in the fact that you cannot assign a value of type `Foo` to a variable of type `Mungeable`, and `var x Mungeable = new(Foo)` is fine. On the contrary, if your `Munge` method is defined as so

```
func (f Foo) Munge() {}
```

Then both `Foo` and `*Foo` would implement `Mungeable`.

The second mistake of yours is that `func (f *Box[Foo]) Print()` does not define a method with the receiver of type `Box[Foo]`, it defines a method with the receiver of generics type `Box` with the type parameter declared as `Foo`. In other words, it is the same as `func (f *Box[T]) Print()`. If you want to act on `Box[Foo]` only, then I think you must put it in the parameter list, as I don't think Go allows specialisation of generics classes.

The solution to your problem is that you can just make `Contents` of type `T` and change type parameter to `*Foo`, like this:

```
package main

type Mungeable interface {
    Munge() // a Mungeable is a thing that can be Munge'd
}

type Box[T Mungeable] struct {
    Contents T // A box is a type based on a Mungeable
}

type Foo struct{} // Foo is a struct...

func (f *Foo) Munge() {} // ...that can be munged.

func Print(b *Box[*Foo]) {
     b.Contents.Munge()
}
```

Comment: I follow you so far.  Thank you.

Now... how do I declare Print to be a method on Box?

Comment: You can declare as you did, `func (b *Box[T]) Print()`, note that you can only declare methods that are the same for all type parameter values of `Box`